# Search String in Txt File

Tags: java, string

We wrote this code in class and I'm having trouble understanding/manipulating it. I want to modify it so it will take a user input, instead of searching the whole file, and print out the position of the word in the file.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

public class Assingment7 {

    public Map<String, Integer> getWordCount(String fileName){

        FileInputStream fis = null;
        DataInputStream dis = null;
        BufferedReader br = null;
        Map<String, Integer> wordMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        try {
            fis = new FileInputStream(fileName);
            dis = new DataInputStream(fis);
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(dis));
            String line = null;
            while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
                StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(line, " ");
                while(st.hasMoreTokens()){
                    String tmp = st.nextToken().toLowerCase();
                    if(wordMap.containsKey(tmp)){
                        wordMap.put(tmp, wordMap.get(tmp)+1);
                    } else {
                        wordMap.put(tmp, 1);
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally{
            try{if(br != null) br.close();}catch(Exception ex){}
        }
        return wordMap;
    }

    public List<Entry<String, Integer>> sortByValue(Map<String, Integer> wordMap){

        Set<Entry<String, Integer>> set = wordMap.entrySet();
        List<Entry<String, Integer>> list = new ArrayList<Entry<String, Integer>>(set);
        Collections.sort( list, new Comparator<Map.Entry<String, Integer>>()
        {
            public int compare( Map.Entry<String, Integer> o1, Map.Entry<String, Integer> o2 )
            {
                return (o2.getValue()).compareTo( o1.getValue() );
            }
        } );
        return list;
    }

    public static void main(String a[]){
        Assingment7 mdc = new Assingment7();
        Map<String, Integer> wordMap = mdc.getWordCount("C://fox.txt");
        List<Entry<String, Integer>> list = mdc.sortByValue(wordMap);
        for(Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry:list){
            System.out.println(entry.getKey()+" ==== "+entry.getValue());
        }
    }
}
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you wanting the line number, word number, paragraph number, or anything else specific about the location of the word?

Comment: I want to print out the line where the word is used

Comment: No need for DataInputStream. Good case for using Java 7 try-with-resources, and you only need a FileReader and a BufferedReader. Anyway, there is no need for anything more than the method that reads the file line-by-line, which could be changed to return an int with the line number when it finds the word (or -1 if it doesn't find it).

Answer (score 0):

You could change your main method to be something like this - the user enters the string they want to search in the console, and if this key is found in the map, it outputs the the value associated with it.

```
public static void main(String a[]) {
    Assingment7 mdc = new Assingment7();
    Map<String, Integer> wordMap = mdc.getWordCount("C://fox.txt");
    List<Entry<String, Integer>> list = mdc.sortByValue(wordMap);

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    String input = null;

    try {
      input = br.readLine();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }

    for(Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry:list) {
        if(entry.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase(input)){
            System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " ==== " + entry.getValue());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How would I change this to output the line(s) where the user input word is used?

Comment: Well there may be many occurrences of the word in the file, but you could change the Map object so that as well as having a string and integer associated with each input it also holds the line number where  each word was found?